# Memoizing a data structure containing a Double in Haskell

Tags: haskell, memoization

I would like to memoize a function that takes a data structure that contains a Double (amongst other things). Neither [MemoTrie](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MemoTrie-0.6.1/docs/Data-MemoTrie.html), nor [Memoize](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/memoize-0.8.1/docs/Data-Function-Memoize.html) supports Double memoization (probably because it's hard to define a complete domain for Double values).  [UglyMemo](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/uglymemo-0.1.0.1/docs/Data-MemoUgly.html) works but I'd like to explore a trully pure and lazy Haskell'ish approach. I'm not considering [StableMemo](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stable-memo-0.3.1/docs/Data-StableMemo.html) since it uses pointer comparison under the hood instead of lazy evaluation and lookup.

Comment: It wouldn't be too difficult to define a `HasTrie Double` instance, but it would probably not be useful in practice, at least not with acceptable memory consumption. The problem is that `Double` usually represents real numbers, which have uncountable cardinality, making memoisation of general functions on it impractical. What _can_ be memoised is _continuous_ functions on ℝ _approximately_. I don't know if that's applicable to your use case, but you could check out https://icfp19.sigplan.org/details/FHPNC-2019-papers/3/Lazy-Evaluation-in-Infinite-Dimensional-Function-Spaces-with-Wavelet-Basis.

Comment: Maybe best show the code in which you actually want to use this memoised function.

Comment: @leftaroundabout `Double` is usually only 64 bits or so -- far from uncountable. I don't see why the memory consumption of a `Double` trie should be any worse than that for a `Word64` trie, and the libraries almost always offer those.

Comment: Just use [`decodeFloat`/`encodeFloat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:decodeFloat)

Comment: @DanielWagner the problem _in practice_ is that a computation that looks up “the same” `Double` value over and over again will usually actually end up looking up lots of different, merely nearby values. So not only does it take a long time before the memoisation actually accomplishes anything (because many values need to be computed before you hit one that's actually stored already), also you waste lots of space storing essentially redundant values.

Comment: ...granted, that's not the case for _all_ applications that use floating values, but those that actually have exact values should probably be using `Rational` in the first place. Whereas the _interesting_ uses of floats are inherently in-exact.